# How to get signed envelop in docusign

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am working on Docusign and PHP scripting language. 
I have completed signing process and i get response from this code.

```
$response = $service->views->getRecipientView(
                $returnUrl, 
                $envelopeId, 
                $contact_name,
                $contact_email,
                $client_id,
                $authMethod);
```

Now i need to get envelop that are signed by user. I get signed envelop in mail but i need to download it from script or get docusign url from which i can download.It would be great help if anyone give solution or provide any link.

Answer (score 2):

You successfully get the embedded recipient (signer) view url, redirect to it, and the signer signs.

Now you want to retrieve the signed documents? (And the Certificate of Completion too?)

Use the EnvelopeDocuments::List method. [Here is a recipe which retrieves the signed files.](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/get-an-envelopes-document-list)

You should first check the envelope status to ensure that the envelope was *completed*.

Comment: Thanks a lot Larry