# Docusign Get one combined document

Tags: docusignapi

with reference to the question ([How to get signed envelop in docusign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216789/how-to-get-signed-envelop-in-docusign))

I'm uploading 3 documents to docusign after signing process is completed I want to download one single combined document (consisting of 3 documents that I uploaded + certificate). I saw the API guid which refers to envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(AccountId, envelopeId, null). This returns us back the CombinedURI. But I'm not sure how to actually download the whole document as one single document with the combined URI.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want a GET to /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/combined

Comment: Thanks. So should it look like "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountid}/envelopes/9b4a97dc-3c49-4651-9fe0-b9e639fb404d/documents/combined"

Comment: Correct, you will receive the response in a PDF byte stream.

Answer (score 7):

```
envelopesApi.getDocument(accountId, envelopeId, "combined")
```

That gets me the signed PDF document(s) for the given envelope.